# Text auto-sizing in TextView inside GridLayout

Tags: java, android, layout, grid

I'm trying to make a GridLayout programatically. The grid consists of interleaved rows of textViews that display titles, and rows of textViews that display data.

Every title textView and the first data textView from the first row is set to auto-size its text with:`TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(textView, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);`

The problem I'm having is that the height of the first row of data textViews is greater than all of the other data textView rows.
From what I've seen, this happens because of the first textView that has text auto-sizing enabled, and even tough the data textViews have all the same weight.

My question is: is there any way to correct this while still having auto-sizing enabled on that first textview?

Clarification: this is my first question ever in StackOverflow so I hope its structure is alright.

I attach my code so you can check it out:

```
public void crear_layout(int cant_datos){
    GridLayout gridLayout = mView.findViewById(R.id.grid);

    gridLayout.removeAllViews();

    int total = cant_datos * 2;
    int column = 3;
    int row = total / column;

    gridLayout.setColumnCount(column);
    gridLayout.setRowCount(row + 1);
    gridLayout.setOrientation(GridLayout.VERTICAL);

    //Logic for creating the rows and setting tags for each textview(id's)
    boolean va_titulo = true;
    int cant_tit_per_column = (total + column - 1) / (column * 2);
    for (int id_titulo, id_dato, i = 0, col = 0, cont_datos = 0 ; i < total; i++) {

        if (cont_datos == cant_tit_per_column){
            col++;
            cont_datos = 0;
        }

        id_titulo = column * cont_datos + col;
        id_dato = column * cont_datos + col;

        if(va_titulo && id_titulo < cant_datos) {
            add_view_title(gridLayout, id_titulo);
            va_titulo = false;
        }
        else if (id_dato < cant_datos){
            add_view_data(gridLayout, id_dato);
            va_titulo = true;
            cont_datos++;
        }
    }
}

private void add_view_title(GridLayout gridLayout, int id){
    AppCompatTextView textView = new AppCompatTextView(activity);

    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setMaxLines(1);
    //...Other customizations like custom background, tag(the purpose of int id) and font style...

    GridLayout.Spec rowSpan;
    GridLayout.Spec colspan;

    TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(textView, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);

    rowSpan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1,(float)0.2);
    colspan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1,1);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams textviewparams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    textView.setLayoutParams(textviewparams);

    GridLayout.LayoutParams gridParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(rowSpan, colspan);

    gridLayout.addView(textView, gridParam);
}

private void add_view_data(GridLayout gridLayout, int id){

    AppCompatTextView textView = new AppCompatTextView(activity);

    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setMaxLines(1);
    //...Other customizations like custom background, tag(the purpose of int id) and font style...

    GridLayout.Spec rowSpan;
    GridLayout.Spec colspan;

    TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(textView, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);

    rowSpan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1,1);
    colspan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1,1);

    GridLayout.LayoutParams textviewparams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    textView.setLayoutParams(textviewparams);

    GridLayout.LayoutParams gridParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(rowSpan, colspan);

    gridLayout.addView(textView, gridParam);
}
```

**EDIT:**
I was able to solve this problem by using nested Linear Layouts. Basically, I made Linear Layouts for every row. Then I put these layouts inside a vertical Linear Layout.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up all your constraints except for the height one 
and
set `textView`'s `scrollEnabled` to `NO`.

You can refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview). Ultimately, your text view will resize automatically depending on its text value.